# Are the items crafted by blacksmith affected by magic find rate?

Tags: diablo-iii

Should I put on '+chance of finding magic items' gear on while crafting? Can this influence the quality of the craft? I know that the number of magical properties is constant per recipe, but is the bonus strength affected by this?

Eg. a 'of Wounding' item gives a +1-2 damage or +3-4 on a level 3 item - is the chance of getting the better version affected by Magic Find?

Comment: This calls for *science*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the information of [Diablo 3 Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Magic_find), that property only affects "*the odds for found items (from monsters or objects) to be "higher quality""*, so nothing to do with Blacksmith or crafting.

Comment: I just don't trust that wiki thatt much, as it still has most articles talking about "that will have to be confirmed once the game is released".

Comment: You should clarify that. From what you are saying it sound almost like "if you have high magic find, the magical properties of found items will be of higher quality", which is absolutely wrong. Item quality is referring to the property which in the auction house is named "rarity" and can be selected in a dropdown menu (inferior, normal, superior, magic, rare, legendary).

Comment: An example of how it works. First, the game determines what item should be dropped. In this example, the game drops a chain mail. Magic find has no impact on this selection. After the type of item has been determined, the rarity of the item is determined (i.e. is it a normal or a magic item etc?). This is where the magic find plays a rule. If you have high magic find, the dropped chain mail has a higher chance of being blue, instead of being just a normal item.

Comment: So, when it comes to the answer to the OP:s question, the answer is "no, magic find does not affect crafting". Because magic find only increases the chances of items being blue. Magic find does not increase the quality of the magical properties. And, when you are crafting, you generally already know that the item you are crafting is going to be blue.

Answer (score 10):

Magic find never affects the selection of affixes for an item, only the base quality of the item.  Since this is pre-determined during crafting, magic find has no affect.

Comment: Would you have anything to back this up?

Comment: @skolima MF has only ever affected the percentage chance that a drop will be magical, set, unique, etc. It is even worded "chance to *find* magic items," not "chance for items to have better stats" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an old post, but for anybody looking for these kinds of answers ...

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find

Most of the info that people replied with above is wrong.  No, MF doesn't affect crafting, only gear that is dropped from killing monsters.  Yes, MF affects both the quality of the item and number of affixes on the item.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the "finding" abilities influence the crafting. 
I always have many "chance of finding magic items" equipped and I do not see changement with the change of the % ammount of this bonus so i don't think so. 
But crafting the same item mutiple time the bonus and abilities of the item crafted improves.

Answer (score -2):

There is one way to find out.

Get enough ingredients and cash to craft 20 of an item.

Craft 10. leave the game. come back in, buff MF (including all 5 neph. stack) and craft the next 10.

I put money on the second set being better, especially when neph. stack at 5.

Comment: If you find out anything by testing this, let us know!

Comment: I'll take that money.